# Webkit.Net DocumentText not updating

Tags: winforms, webkit, webkit.net

I'm currently using a [WebkitBrowser for .NET](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/) component in a Win form application in order to render HTML.
The application generate html code in a richtextbox and I want it to be display in the the webkit browser in real time. 
Here is my code:

```
public void Write_HTML(string html)
{                        
    HTMLTag.Text = html;            
}
```

This is a method call from another class in order to update the html content in the richtextbox

```
private void HTMLTag_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HTMLTag.Refresh();
    webKitBrowser.DocumentText = HTMLTag.Text;
}
```

Each time the text of the rich textbox is change I tried to set the Webkit browser html content. after this affectation the DocumentText is still empty and I cannot understand why.

The funny part is that is I go on the interface and change the contetn of the textbox then the webpart refresh accordingly but is the event is trigger by the mthod Write_HTML it doesn't work, and no idea why. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To get actual document text, you can use following:

```
webKitBrowser.StringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.documentElement.innerHTML");
```